# Openoffice / Excel combine multiple worksheets into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, mysql, openoffice

I have not yet found the exact answer to my specific problem, so let's give it a shot :

The Layout :

1 SharePoint Farm on which a report was run, returning **6** Excel Files with each containing **250 Worksheets** with exactly **4001** rows in it (last worksheet in File 6 has a few less ... )

Every single worksheet has the very same and exact layout :

```
Row 1 : header (A-N)
row 2 - 4001 : Data (A-N , 4k rows)
```

The issue I'm having is that I need to evaluate the Data in those 6 Files for a report , my thinking was to have the data imported into a mysql DB and then a simple website with a few queries to be set up to filter for a few specific rows (failure / sucess ) and then pull the resulting item / document / site collection etc.

The Problem however is that due to the sheer number of worksheets I do not really want to go ahead and C&P every single one , that would consume way too much time. The other issue is, that Excel / OO only saves CSV per active worksheet , again , no joy.

The Report itself can be obtained as a single txt (csv) file as well, delimited by semicolon but without text qualifiers.

As the report contains a list of all items, documents and object within the Farm , this is pretty much useless as well, as a rough count has revealed a good 900k items have somewhere a ; in the name , which without a text qualifier makes it impossible to import into a database.

So, the Q I'm really after :

(either Excel or openoffice) :

Would somebody be able to provide me with a function that copies the data from all worksheets into a "consolidated" one until the limit of 65,536 rows has been reached and then a new consolidated worksheet is being started.

As Excel / Openoffice allows to save the data with text qualifiers, that would make my life a lot simpler. I would end up importing into mysql only a few dozen files instead of thousands.

So, any ideas on how to attack this issue ?
Perhaps MS Access, but havent found a way yet to import all worksheets into Access , which brings me back to an insane copy and paste day.

Of course, if any other suggestions come to mind, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

[Ron de Bruin Excel Automation](http://www.rondebruin.nl/index.htm) has many pages with useful free Excel VBA Tips and Excel Add-ins.

I think [RDBMerge, Excel Merge Add-in for Excel for Windows](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm) may be just what you need.

> RDBMerge is a user friendly way to Merge Data from Multiple Excel Workbooks,
>   csv and xml files into a Summary Workbook.
>
> Install the RDBMerge utility
>
> 1) Download the correct version and extract it to a local directory.
>
> 2) Copy RDBMerge.xla(m) to a unprotected directory on your system.
>        Tip: Use one folder for all your add-ins (easy to backup your add-ins this way)
>
> 3) Start Excel and open a workbook.
>
> Excel 97-2003
>
> Click Tools, click Add-Ins, use "Browse" to go to the
>   add-in and then click OK. Verify RDBMerge is checked in the add-in
>   list and then click OK.
>
> Excel 2007-2013
>
> 2007: Click the Microsoft Office Button, click Excel Options, 
>   click the Add-Ins tab.
>
> 2010-2013: Click on File, click on
>   Options, click the Add-ins tab. In the Manage drop-down, choose Excel
>   Add-ins, and click Go. Use “Browse” to go to the add-in and then click
>   on OK. Verify RDBMerge is checked in the add-in list and then click
>   OK.
>
> [image]

There are detailed step-by-step instructions and download links in the rest of the article.

You can also search his site for "merge spreadsheets" for other possiblities.

Comment: the addin is asking for a password